# File Uploader is not Showing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is the screenshot of this code:

[image]

I want to upload files with different formats. I think it is due to sidebar. Because I have run the same code in New Project and that was working perfectly. I want to upload files with different formats. I think it is due to sidebar. Because I have run the same code in New Project and that was working perfectly:

```
@model IEnumerable<ObjFile>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    /*   .btn {
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            background: #00BCD4;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: white;
            color: white;
        }

        .gridborder {
            border-top: 1px solid #DED8D8;
        }*/
</style>

<div>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "submitFYPReport", FormMethod.Post,
     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        if (TempData["Message"] != null)
        {

            <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 200; color: red">@TempData["Message"]</p>
        }
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50px;">
                        <b style="color: #FF5722">File:</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    }
    <table class="gridborder row-borderhover order-column dataTable no-footer">
        <tr>
            <th class="sorting_asc">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.File)
            </th>
            <th class="sorting">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Size)
            </th>
            <th class="sorting">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
            </th>
            <th class="sorting"></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="sorting_1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.File)
                </td>
                <td class="sorting_1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)
                </td>
                <td class="sorting_1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                </td>
                <th class="sorting">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { fileName = item.File })
                </th>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "submitFYPReport", FormMethod.Post,
     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` get rid of the second `@`. So `@using(Html.BeginForm(...))`.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem.  On Simple page it is workinng fine. But with sidebar it is not working

Comment: Examine the rendered page source to be sure the html exists. The browser's tools will let you inspect the applied css rules which can help you determine why it is not displayed.